# TYPO3 multilanguage preview not showing second language

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I've got a TYPO3 page with two languages the default one and english.

Now when I press the view button on the secondary language to get the prview page with the URL `www.domain.de/home/?L=2`. But the page is the german version and not the english one?

I'm using realurl could that be the problem?

**Update Typoscript**

```
#xhtml_cleaning = all damit wird mit "/" ausgegeben
uniqueLinkVars        = 1
linkVars              = L(1-3)
sys_language_uid      = 0
sys_language_overlay  = hideNonTranslated
sys_language_mode     = content_fallback
language              = de
locale_all            = de_DE.UTF-8
htmlTag_langKey       = de  
intTarget         = _self
extTarget             = _blank
}
```

and this

```
CONTENTMAIN = CONTENT
CONTENTMAIN.table = tt_content
CONTENTMAIN.select.where = colPos = 0  
CONTENTMAIN.select.languageField = sys_language_uid
CONTENTMAIN.select.orderBy = sorting
```

UPDATE:
actual full Typoscript (setup)

```
# Responsive Design Optimization

tt_content.image.20 {
imageStdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="csc-textpic-imagewrap1"> | </div>
imageColumnStdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="csc-textpic-imagecolumn"> | </div>
}
tt_content.image.20 {
rendering {
dl {
imageRowStdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="csc-textpic-imagerow"> | </div>
imageLastRowStdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="csc-textpic-imagerow csc-textpic-imagerow-last"> | </div>
oneImageStdWrap.dataWrap = <dl class="csc-textpic-image###CLASSES###" > | </dl>
}
ul {
imageRowStdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="csc-textpic-imagerow"><ul> | </ul></div>
imageLastRowStdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="csc-textpic-imagerow csc-textpic-imagerow-last"><ul> | </ul></div>
oneImageStdWrap.dataWrap = <li class="csc-textpic-image###CLASSES###"> | </li>
}
div {
imageRowStdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="csc-textpic-imagerow"> | </div>
imageLastRowStdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="csc-textpic-imagerow csc-textpic-imagerow-last"> | </div>
oneImageStdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="csc-textpic-image###CLASSES###"> | </div>
}
simple {
imageStdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="csc-textpic-imagewrap csc-textpic-single-image"> | </div>
}
}
}

tt_content.image.20 {
renderMethod = figure
rendering {
figure {
imageRowStdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="csc-textpic-imagerow"> | </div>
imageLastRowStdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="csc-textpic-imagerow csc-textpic-imagerow-last"> | </div>
noRowsStdWrap.wrap =
oneImageStdWrap.dataWrap = <figure class="csc-textpic-image"> | </figure>
imgTagStdWrap.wrap = |
editIconsStdWrap.wrap = <div> | </div>
caption.wrap = <figcaption> | </figcaption>
caption.required = 1
}
}
}


#CONFIGURATION####################

[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
config {
  sys_language_uid = 2
  language         = en
  locale_all       = en_US.UTF-8
  htmlTag_langKey  = en
}
[global]

config {

# headerComment (
#Diese Seite wurde erstellt von:
#DeWo Werbeagentur OHG
#Zuständig für Layout-Umsetzung  
#dewo.de
#)


doctype = html5 
renderCharset = utf-8
metaCharset = utf-8
prefixLocalAnchors = all
simulateStaticDocuments = 0
tx_realurl_enable = 1
absRefPrefix = /  

spamProtectEmailAddresses = 2
spamProtectEmailAddresses_atSubst = (at)
// Cache settings
cache_period = 43200
 #Entfernt Kommentare um die content elements  
disablePrefixComment = 1
index_enable = 1
removeDefaultJS = external
admPanel = 1
sendCacheHeaders = 1  

#xhtml_cleaning = all damit wird mit "/" ausgegeben
uniqueLinkVars        = 1
linkVars              = L(1-3)
sys_language_uid      = 0
sys_language_overlay  = hideNonTranslated
sys_language_mode     = content_fallback
language              = de
locale_all            = de_DE.UTF-8
htmlTag_langKey       = de  
intTarget         = _self
extTarget             = _blank
}

page = PAGE

page {
    typeNum = 0

   shortcutIcon = fileadmin/bilder/favicon.png

    appletouchicon =
    insertClassesFromRTE = 1
    adminPanelStyles = 1      

    # The meta Tags for the page. 

    meta {
        # Description - auslesen und ggf. vererben wenn kein entry auf single page
        description.data = page:description
        description.ifEmpty.data = levelfield :-1, description, slide

        # Keywords - auslesen und ggf. vererben wenn kein entry auf single page
        keywords.data = page:keywords
        keywords.ifEmpty.data = levelfield :-1, keywords, slide
        keywords.keywords = 1
        date.data = page:SYS_LASTCHANGED // page:crdate;
        date.date = Y-m-d
        author = 
        publisher = 
        copyright = 
        PAGE-TOPIC = Information
        PAGE-TYPE  = Information

        language.data = TSFE:lang
        robots = index, follow
        siteinfo = robots.txt
        revisit-after = 7 days

        viewport = width = device-width, initial-scale=1.0

        }

    includeJSlibs {
      jquery = fileadmin/config/script/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js
      jquery.forceOnTop = 1
    }



    includeCSS { 

        #a standard Grid system based on the boilertemplate
        boil = fileadmin/config/script/css/boilerplate.css
        boil.media = screen
        boil.forceOnTop = 1


         # our own navigation stylesheet 
        mefish = fileadmin/config/script/css/megafish.css
        mefish.media = only screen and (min-width: 768px)
        mefish.forceOnTop = 0

        # Grid file based on the boilertemplate
        grid = fileadmin/config/script/css/grid.css
        grid.media = screen
        grid.forceOnTop = 0

         # our own stylesheet
        flex = fileadmin/config/script/css/flexslider_styles.css
        flex.media = screen
        flex.forceOnTop = 0   

        # icon font
        awe = fileadmin/config/script/font-awesome-4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css
        awe.media = screen
        awe.forceOnTop = 0

        # IndexSearch Template
        indexSearch = fileadmin/customDesign/indexsearch/css/indexsearch-style.css
        indexSearch.media = screen
        indexSearch.forceOnTop = 0      

        }

 }
      # END Page object


# blendet Subnavi aus, 
[globalVar = TSFE:page|layout = 1]
  page.includeCSS   {
        subnav = fileadmin/config/script/css/subnavi.css
        subnav.media = screen
        subnav.forceOnTop = 0
      }
 [global]

)


page.20 = TEMPLATE
page.20.template = FILE
page.20.template.file = fileadmin/config/script/template/template.html

  page.20 {

   workOnSubpart = DOCUMENT

  marks {
    #links   
    INHALTOBEN = CONTENT
    INHALTOBEN.table = tt_content
    INHALTOBEN.select.where = colPos = 1   
    INHALTOBEN.select.languageField = sys_language_uid
    INHALTOBEN.select.orderBy = sorting

    #normal
    CONTENTMAIN = CONTENT
    CONTENTMAIN.table = tt_content
    CONTENTMAIN.select.where = colPos = 0  
    CONTENTMAIN.select.languageField = sys_language_uid
    CONTENTMAIN.select.orderBy = sorting

    #rechts
    CONTENTASIDE = CONTENT
    CONTENTASIDE.table = tt_content
    CONTENTASIDE.select.where = colPos = 2
    CONTENTASIDE.select.languageField = sys_language_uid
    CONTENTASIDE.select.orderBy = sorting

    #rand
    OBEN = CONTENT
    OBEN.table = tt_content
    OBEN.select.where = colPos = 3
    OBEN.select.languageField = sys_language_uid
    OBEN.select.orderBy = sorting

    #Hier in Zeile 220 die id von der Seite 'static' eingeben (Änderung 15.05.14 Florian Kasischke)
    #NAVISTATIC = HMENU
    #NAVISTATIC.special = directory
    #NAVISTATIC.special.value = 
    #NAVISTATIC.excludeUidList = ,
    #NAVISTATIC {
    #1 = TMENU
    #1 {
    #expAll = 1
    #wrap = <ul class="headernavmenu">|</ul>
    #noBlur = 1
    #NO = 1
    #NO.ATagTitle.field = title
    #NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>

    #NO.allWrap =   |  I  |*| |  I  |*| |
    #ACT < .NO
    #ACT.ATagParams = class="active_static"
    #}
    #}    

    BREAD = HMENU
    BREAD {
      special = rootline
      special.range = 0 | 2
      1 = TMENU
      1.NO.ATagTitle.field = title
      1.NO.ATagParams = class="staticbread"
      1.NO.allWrap = |  /  |*| |  /  |*| |

    }

    NAVIMAIN = HMENU
    NAVIMAIN.entryLevel = 0
    #NAVIMAIN.excludeUidList = 

    NAVIMAIN {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
    expAll = 1
    wrap = <ul class="sf-menu">|</ul>
    noBlur = 1
    NO = 1
    NO.ATagTitle.field = title
    NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>  
    ACT = 1
    ACT.ATagParams = class="act"
    ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li> |</li>  

     }

    2 = TMENU
    2 {
    expAll = 1
    maxItems = 10
    wrap = <div class="sf-mega">|</div>
    NO = 1
    NO {
      ATagTitle.field = title
      wrapItemAndSub = <div class="sf-mega-section">|</div>
      stdWrap.wrap = |
      ATagParams =  class="headermega"
      stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
      doNotLinkIt = 0
      }
    }

    3 = TMENU
    3 {
    expAll = 1
    maxItems = 20
    wrap = <ul>|</ul>
    NO = 1
    NO {
      ATagTitle.field = title
      linkWrap = <li>|</li>
    }
    ACT = 1
    ACT {
      wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
      ATagParams =  class="active"
    }
    }
    #4 < .3

   }


    NAVIOFF = HMENU
    NAVIOFF.entryLevel = 0
    #NAVIOFF.excludeUidList = 
    NAVIOFF {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
    expAll = 1
    wrap = <ul class="sf-menu">|</ul>
    noBlur = 1
    NO = 1
    NO.ATagTitle.field = title
    NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
    IFSUB = 1
    IFSUB < .NO
    IFSUB.ATagParams = class="pfeile"  

     ACT = 1
     ACT < .NO
     ACT.ATagParams = class="menuakt"
     CUR = 1
     CUR < .ACT

    }
    2 < .1  
    2.wrap = <ul>|</ul>
    2.NO.wrapItemAndSub =  <li class="first"> |</li> |*| <li> |</li> |*| <li class="last"> | </li>   
    2.ACT = 0

    3 < .2
    4 < .2
    }

    SUBNAVI = HMENU
    SUBNAVI.entryLevel = 1
    SUBNAVI.excludeUidList = 3,754,68
    SUBNAVI {

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
    expAll = 1
    wrap =  <ul>|</ul>
    noBlur = 1
    NO = 1
    NO.ATagTitle.field = title
    NO.ATagParams =  style="border-bottom:2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);"  
    NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
    IFSUB = 1
    IFSUB < .NO
    #IFSUB.stdWrap.dataWrap=|&nbsp;&nbsp;&#9662;
      #&#9662;
    #IFSUB.ATagParams = class="pfeile"    
    ACT < .NO
    ACT.ATagParams = class="subactive"

    #IFSUB = 1
   # IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="menuparent">|</li>
    #ACTIFSUB < .IFSUB
    # wenn unterseiten vorhanden, dann kann Icon angezeigt werden
    # IFSUB = 1
   # IFSUB.stdWrap.dataWrap=&raquo;&nbsp;|
    }

      2 < .1
      2 {
      expAll = 0
      }
      3 < .2 
      3 = TMENU
      3 {
      expAll = 1  
      NO.ATagParams = style="padding-left:1.5rem;font-size:0.875rem;"
      ACT < .NO
      ACT.ATagParams = class="subactive" style="padding-left:1.5rem;font-size:0.875rem;" 
      }
    #4 < .3

    }

   }

 }


## Localization menu:
lib.langMenu = HMENU
lib.langMenu {
        special = language
        special.value = 0,1,2
        special.normalWhenNoLanguage = 0
        1 = GMENU
        1.NO {
                XY = [5.w]+4, [5.h]+4
                backColor = white
                5 = IMAGE
                5.file = EXT:cms/tslib/media/flags/flag_uk.gif  || EXT:cms/tslib/media/flags/flag_de.gif
                5.offset = 2,2
        }

        1.ACT < lib.langMenu.1.NO
        1.ACT=1
        1.ACT.backColor = black

        1.USERDEF1 < lib.langMenu.1.NO
        1.USERDEF1=1
        1.USERDEF1.5.file = EXT:cms/tslib/media/flags/flag_uk.gif  || EXT:cms/tslib/media/flags/flag_de.gif
        1.USERDEF1.noLink = 0

        1.USERDEF2 < lib.langMenu.1.USERDEF1
        1.USERDEF2.backColor = green
}
```

Comment: Please add your typoscript language configuration here

Comment: added the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include configuration that changes the language depending on the value of the `L` parameter:

```
config {
  sys_language_uid = 0
  language         = de
  locale_all       = de_DE.UTF-8
  htmlTag_langKey  = de
}
[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
config {
  sys_language_uid = 2
  language         = en
  locale_all       = en_US.UTF-8
  htmlTag_langKey  = en
}
[global]
```

Repeat this for all the languages with the accordant language ID (uid of the language record).

EDIT: The conditional block should be below the default block for language 0; added that.

Comment: tried this, I added the code above to the template setup. I chaned the 1 to a 2 because english is 2.

But nothing changed.

Chache is cleared ...

Comment: I've added my full typoscript above

Comment: As TypoScript is evaluated sequentially, you need to include the condition block I posted *below* the first assignment, otherwise it gets overwritten again.

Answer (score 1):

You have the condition for language switch at the top of your typoscript. Later you override the `config.sys_language_uid` with the default value of `0`.

So you have to put your condition at the bottom of your typoscript.